# elasticsearch disk usage / indexes size

Tags: elasticsearch

i use elasticsearch and when i use _cat/allocation/:

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent                
    10        4.9mb    51.4gb    956.3gb   1007.8gb            5 
    10        4.7mb    51.5gb    956.2gb   1007.8gb            5
```

disk.used is over 50GB

using _cat/shards:

```
index                     shard prirep state   docs    store           
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      STARTED  724  572.8kb 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      STARTED  724  539.7kb 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     r      STARTED  673  997.8kb
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      STARTED  673  969.8kb 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     p      STARTED  699      1mb
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     r      STARTED  699  556.9kb 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      STARTED  670      1mb 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      STARTED  670  546.7kb
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     p      STARTED  722 1013.1kb
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     r      STARTED  722 1020.8kb
```

```
health status index                     pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
green  open   read_me                     5   1          0            0      1.5kb           795b 
green  open   cs-card-logs_20180712-001   5   1       3106            0      4.8mb          2.4mb
```

the store size is lower than 5mb

using /_cat/segments/

```
index                     shard prirep segment generation docs.count docs.deleted    size size.memory committed searchable version compound 
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     p      _5u            210        245            0 209.7kb       45308 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     p      _5v            211          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     p      _5w            212          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     r      _5u            210        243            0 207.8kb       45243 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     r      _5v            211          2            0  10.4kb        8095 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     r      _5w            212          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 0     r      _5x            213          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _50            180        188            0 178.4kb       44552 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _51            181          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _52            182          2            0  10.4kb        8095 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _53            183          1            0   4.4kb        3262 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _54            184          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _55            185          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _56            186          1            0   4.4kb        3262 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _57            187          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     r      _58            188          2            0   8.3kb        6826 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _50            180        189            0 178.7kb       44568 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _51            181          2            0  10.4kb        8095 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _52            182          1            0   4.4kb        3262 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _53            183          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _54            184          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _55            185          1            0   4.4kb        3262 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _56            186          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 1     p      _57            187          2            0   8.3kb        6826 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     p      _64            220        240            0 209.8kb       45900 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     p      _65            221          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     r      _64            220        238            0 209.8kb       45873 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     r      _65            221          1            0   4.8kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     r      _66            222          1            0   4.4kb        3262 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 2     r      _67            223          1            0     5kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     r      _5u            210        226            0 207.1kb       45876 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     r      _5v            211          1            0   6.5kb        5269 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     r      _5w            212          2            0  39.5kb       27250 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      _5u            210        223            0 205.6kb       45812 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      _5v            211          2            0  10.4kb        8095 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      _5w            212          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      _5x            213          1            0   6.5kb        5269 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 3     p      _5y            214          2            0  39.5kb       27250 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _64            220        240            0   207kb       45498 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _65            221          1            0   4.8kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _66            222          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _67            223          1            0   5.1kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _68            224          1            0   6.7kb        5397 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     p      _69            225          2            0  40.2kb       27796 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _64            220        240            0 207.1kb       45506 true      true       5.5.2   false    
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _65            221          1            0   4.8kb        3872 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _66            222          1            0   5.2kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _67            223          1            0   5.1kb        4113 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _68            224          1            0   6.7kb        5397 true      true       5.5.2   true     
cs-card-logs_20180712-001 4     r      _69            225          2            0  40.2kb       27796 true      true       5.5.2   true
```

I can't figure why is my disk usage so high ?

what can i do to find the reason of this disk.used ?

how can i check what is taking that's much space ?

did someone can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figured reported by the `disk.used` column is the disk space used in total, i.e. also outside of ES.

The size used by ES is in the `disk.indices` column. This column [was added](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13529) in order to provide more insights into the ES vs non-ES disk usage.

So in order to find out what's taking up disk space, you can leverage the `du` command at the root of your filesystem, but it's not ES.